# Selecting 3 rows into 3 columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to select the 3 rows into 3 columns, but i get NULL values.

Here is my code so far:

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
   SELECT t_k
   FROM m_t_k 
   WHERE p_id = 5 and t_k_id in (1,2,7)
 ) src
 PIVOT(
   MAX()
   for t_k in ([1],[2],[3])
 ) piv
```

this is the result of the query without the PIVOT
and i want those rows to be on 3 columns

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desire results.

Comment: Could you have more than 3 values? This seems like something for your display layer, not the RDBMS.

Comment: No, they can be only 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` and a Cross Tab to achieve this. This is a bit of a guess, based on  the query and image we have though, so it is untested:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN sq.term_key END) AS term_key1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN sq.term_key END) AS term_key2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN sq.term_key END) AS term_key3
FROM (SELECT term_key,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY term_key) AS RN
      FROM mpos_term_key
      WHERE profile_id = 5
        AND term_keys_type_id IN (1, 2, 7)) sq;
```